# Stop previous animation before start of next animation in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made four `span` which on `mouseOver` animate to `top:20px` and on `mouseOut` animate back to `top:-20px`.

I have written this code:

```
    $(".pull_down").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({top:'20px'});  
    });
    $(".pull_down").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).animate({top:'-20px'}); 
    });
```

All the `span` has same class `pull_down` which has this `CSS style`:

```
.pull_down
{
    -webkit-msie-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);


    background:#900;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    border:#000 solid 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    padding-right:100px;
    z-index:500;
    width:100px;
}
.pull_down:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Basically this is of no use.

**The problem lies here is, if the mouse is passed over these elements more than 1 time, say 7 times, then these animations are queued and this looks awkward**

So what I wanted was when I hover over a span it start its animation and when I switch over another span **the last span is restored to its position**.

One Example is [here](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/43102.html)

I also read related posts for [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) but was unable to figure it out how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the awesome properties of jQuery is method chaining which allows for the serial processing of timed events.

If you rewrite your code using .stop() you should be able to do the trick.

Like this

```
$(".pull_down").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({top:'20px'});  
});
$(".pull_down").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({top:'-20px'}); 
});
```

This will clear the animation queue for the selected DOM object and subsequently add the animation to be processed immediately.

To stop all of the other spans, just reuse the selector inside the call like this

```
$(".pull_down").mouseover(function(){
    $(".pull_down").stop();
    $(this).animate({top:'20px'});  
});
$(".pull_down").mouseout(function(){
    $(".pull_down").stop();
    $(this).animate({top:'-20px'}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

```
$(".pull_down").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({top:'20px'});  
});
$(".pull_down").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({top:'-20px'}); 
});
```